# UITableViewCell custom font only displays after table update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm not doing anything complicated. Just trying to set the font on a table cell. The font displays fine if I reload the table data after the view controller appears or if the table is scrolled and the cell updates itself. But it doesn't display properly if I just set the tableview properties when it loads the first time.

Here's the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"listItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [pickerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor AMFDarkBlueColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor AMFRedColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSlab-500" size:cell.textLabel.font.pointSize];
}
```

Like I said, it works if I call `reloadData` in `viewDidAppear`. That just seems like an unnecessary step so I want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Thanks

*EDIT*
I get the same effect whether I set the font in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `willDisplayCell`

Comment: this is working fine for me. what is the issue. tell me in detail.

Comment: I have to manually call reloadData in viewDidAppear for the font to display. I'm thinking this causes the data to be loaded twice when the view controller loads and once every time the view controller appears. It seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: I would still recommend that you change your cell.textLabel.font inside your cell cell initialization otherwise will be setting the font everything the cell will display on the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try by doing like this

```
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSlab-500" size:17.0];
```

Comment: This was it. Point size is zero on initialization. I guess that was causing the font to fail loading and it reverted back to the default.

Answer (score 1):

Change cell.textLabel.font = ... to right after your cell initiation.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"listItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSlab-500" size:cell.textLabel.font.pointSize];
    }
//Continue cell config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, give it a go:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 30.0 ];
cell.textLabel.font = myFont;   
[cell.textLabel setText:@"Text"];

return cell;
}
```